# JDK-8 - java.awt.event.KeyEvent.getKeyChar() not work

Tags: java, java-8, keyboard

With the code below we have two behaviors, typing Til(**~**) character key.
On jdk 1.8.0_101 are printed character => Til(**~**) 
On Jdk 1.8.0_171 are printed => Undefined() character. 
I search on google and oracle documentation, but not found nothing about this. 
Apparently it's something recent.
Any Ideia?

```
public class Sample extends JFrame {

private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;

public Sample() {
    setSize(200, 80);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jTextField1.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
            System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar());
        }
    });
    add(jTextField1);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Sample().setVisible(true);
}}
```

[image: Jdk 1.8.0_171]
[image: Jdk 1.8.0_101]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#getKeyChar()) of `getKeyChar()` method,

> Returns the character associated with the key in this event. For example, the KEY_TYPED event for shift + "a" returns the value for "A".
>   KEY_PRESSED and KEY_RELEASED events are not intended for reporting of character input. Therefore, the values returned by this method are guaranteed to be meaningful only for KEY_TYPED events.

So if you simply want to report the character typed, you should use the `keyTyped()` instead of `keyReleased()`. It worked for me. Here's the code for `keyTyped()` method:

```
@Override
public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt){
    System.out.println(evt.getKeyChar());
}
```

Comment: Thanks mark42inbound, I have a legacy code where he has stopped working on this JDK because of this behavior change. I'll try this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Using the keyTyped did not work because getKeyChar() also returned me Undefined char. So I do a workaround below on KeyPress.

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
    if (JAVA_8 && evt.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.CHAR_UNDEFINED) {
        callKeyPressedEvent: {
            switch (evt.getKeyCode()) {
                case 129:
                    evt.setKeyChar(((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) == 1) ? '\u0060' : '\u00b4');//` and ´
                    break;
                case 131:
                    evt.setKeyChar(((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) == 1) ? '\u005E' : '\u007E');//^ and ~
                    break;
                case 135:
                    if ((evt.getModifiers() & KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK) == 1) {
                        evt.setKeyChar('\u00a8');//¨
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    break callKeyPressedEvent;
            }

            processKeyEvent(evt);
        }
}
```